# Java game runs slower and slower as game runs longer

Tags: java, frame-rate

I know that this question may be considered off topic, but this is a significant problem.

### Problem:

I have in a java game that I am working on. The FPS counter starts at 250 FPS and in about 2-4 minutes, down to less than 10 FPS. These is too much code to put in this post, but <s>**does anyone know what might cause this?**</s> (Question has been mode to the edit.)

### Edit:

I have found the problem. In short, there are circles moving on a screen. The problem occurs when the program checks if the circle has reached the edge. When the circle reaches the edge, it is killed and particles are summoned. Here is the code for that part(`a` is a circle):

```
if(((Math.abs(a.pos.getX()) + a.radius) >= Game.maxDimention) || ((Math.abs(a.pos.getY()) + a.radius) >= Game.maxDimention)){
    a.die(); //Kill
    a.generateExplosion(); // Summon particles
};
```

When I remove this part, I do not have problems with the game slowing down. **What can I do to fix this?**

### Edit 2:

I have fixed it! The problem was that entities and particles were removed, but the list of particles/entities to remove wasn't being cleared. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @Stephane Hockenhull!

**Thank you for your time.** *If you vote down, please tell me why so I can improve this question.*

Comment: The issue that I think the downvotes meant to point out is that it's difficult to understand what problem the question is representing, except by reading the answers. There are very many reasons that a game might slow down over time and the question on its own doesn't give enough detail to debug it.

Comment: @Anko This was a very broad question. I had no idea what the problem was, so I was asking for suggestions and insights. Stephane Hockenhull was sure able to give a helpful answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have object leaks.

Objects that are still referenced somewhere in an array or list, creating more and more objects for the garbage collector to process as the game advances.

Or more and more AI objects that are off-screen but still active and processing on every frames.

Comment: What would be the best way or me to pinpoint object leaks? Would you recommend calling `System.gc()` every few seconds?